# How to use Autofac to host WCF OData services

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, odata, autofac, was

What is the recommended approach to using Autofac to host a WCF Data Service (OData)?

For non-OData services, we've been using the AppStart.AppInitialize() approach to register the dependencies in a protocol agnostic fashion, and changing the .svc files to use the `AutofacServiceHostFactory`.

But WCF Data Services already have a factory, `System.Data.Services.DataServiceHostFactory, System.Data.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`

Will the `AutofacServiceHostFactory` work for that too? Do we need a new derivative factory?